# Enabling UL-mimo in linux laptops

Tags: wireless, kernel

UL MU-MIMO is an important feature introduced in Wi-Fi 6. UL MU-MIMO uses the multi-antenna technology of the transmitter and receiver to transmit data simultaneously on multiple spatial streams over the same channel. Multiple data streams in UL MU-MIMO come from multiple users.

I have a command for enabling UL-MIMO in Windows using the Windows Registry. Is there any way to find the similar command for enabling UL-MIMO in Linux AX200 laptops? Please consider this as urgent.

Please find the device details,

Command used in Windows:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0010 /v HePhyCapabilitiesDword0 /t REG_DWORD /d 0x42300E /f
```

Device details:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
- Kernel: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic
- Architecture: x86-64
- Hardware Vendor: Dell

Comment: What is ul-mimo ?